# MySQL stored procedure has just stopped working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure setup and it has just stopped working in the last few days.  Does anyone know why this could just stop working?  None of the database tables have changed.

```
    drop procedure if exists bookings_by_voucher;
    delimiter //
    create procedure bookings_by_voucher(in start_date date, in end_date date, l_id int)
    language sql
    deterministic
    sql security definer
    begin
            declare s text;
            select distinct group_concat(concat('sum(if(c.gross_value = ',gross_value,',c.net_value,0)) coupon',
                    cast(gross_value as unsigned))) from coupons into s;
            set @query = concat('select ',if(l_id is null, '"All Locations"','l.location_name'),
            ' location_name,ifnull(b.places, 0) as places, ',
            if(start_date is null and end_date is null,'"All Dates"',
            if(start_date is null, concat('" <= ',end_date,'"'),
            if(end_date is null,concat('" >= ',start_date,'"'),
            concat('"',start_date,' - ',end_date,'"')
            )
            )
            ),' dates,',
            ifnull(s,'"No Coupons"'),
            ',round(sum(b.price/1.2-ifnull(c.net_value,0)), 2) paidbycard from locations l join bookings b ',
            ' on l.id = b.location_id ',
            concat(if(start_date is null,'',concat(' and b.date >= "', start_date,'"'))),
            concat(if(end_date is null,'',concat(' and b.date <= "', end_date,'"'))),
            ' left join coupons c on b.voucher_code = c.code',
            if (l_id is null, ' group by l.id', concat(' where l.id = ', l_id) ));
            /*select @query;*/
            prepare stmt from @query;
            execute stmt;
    end//
```

The error that I am getting back from my application (built in Laravel 5.1) is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'paidbycard
>   from locations l join bookings b  on l.id = b.location_id  left join
>   ' at line 1 (SQL: call bookings_by_voucher(null, null, null))

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information over "stopped working".

Comment: @Matt I have updated my question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something, If I am not wrong, after your "group by" clause there is "where" clause.